# DataFlavor in JavaFX not recognized correctly

Tags: drag-and-drop, imageview, javafx-2

I'm experiencing a problem when D&D a custom object from Swing to JavaFX and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or its probably a Java FX bug.

My Transferable has been defined as the following:

```
public class TransferableEmployee implements Transferable {

  public static final DataFlavor EMPLOYEE_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(Employee[].class, "Employee");
  public static final DataFlavor DEFINITION_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(PropertyDefinition[].class, "Definition");

  private static final DataFlavor FFLAVORS [] = {EMPLOYEE_FLAVOR, DEFINITION_FLAVOR};

  private Employee[] employees;
  private PropertyDefinition[] propertyDefinitions;

  public MintTransferableEmployee(Employee[] employees, PropertyDefinition[] propertyDefinitions) {
    this.employees = employees != null ? employees.clone() : null;
    this.propertyDefinitions = propertyDefinitions != null ? propertyDefinitions.clone() : null;
  }

  public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
    return FFLAVORS.clone();
  }

  public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor aFlavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException  {

    Object returnObject = null;
    if (aFlavor.equals(EMPLOYEE_FLAVOR)) {
      returnObject = employees;
    }
    else if(aFlavor.equals(DEFINITION_FLAVOR)){
      returnObject = propertyDefinitions;
    }
    else{
      throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(aFlavor);
    }
    return returnObject;
  }

  public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor aFlavor) {
    boolean lReturnValue = false;
    for (int i=0, n=FFLAVORS.length; i<n; i++) {
      if (aFlavor.equals(FFLAVORS[i])) {
        lReturnValue = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return lReturnValue;
  }
}
```

I've created an imageView (FX Component) where I added the setOnDragOver just as the following:

```
employeePhotoImageView.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

      @Override
      public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragOver");
        event.getDragboard().getContentTypes();
        event.getDragboard().getContent(DataFormat.lookupMimeType("application/x-java-serialized-object"));

      }
    });
```

The getContentTypes() returns a Map with [[application/x-java-serialized-object]], so now I try to get the Content, and this only returns the List of PropertyDefinition but no Employee at all (which in this case, is the one I need).

If I remove the data of the PropertyDefinition in the transferable, the employee is returned in the getContent(DataFormat) method.

For me, this means that JavaFX only works with 1 DataFlavor or somehow it is only returning the last flavor found in the Transferable.

Any clues on this?

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: Temporarily I've created a new Transferable object called TransferableEmployeeAndProperties, with only 1 DataFlavor which basically its a Pair<T1, T2> in which in this case the T1 is filled with a Employee[] and T2 is a PropertyDefinition[]. But its probably not the best solution so far.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I ran into this problem today. It seems like javafx can only handle a single instance of a particular mime type on the "drag board". I don't know if this is a bug or javafx is being hard nosed about some sort of standard about how the "drag board" is to be used. If I find out more I'll let you know.

Comment: I kept it the way I said in my previous comment, 1 mime type with a custom Pair<T1,T2> object, its working fine under development and executable jar.

Comment: Indeed, that is pretty much what we have had to do. We couldn't find a way to work around it. In the debugger I can see that the "dragboard" is backed by a Map of mime type to content which I think is what is accounting for there only being one instance of a given mime type. If you look at the awt DataFlavor class javadoc you will see that swing supports a class parameter in the mimetype (e.g. "image/x-java-image;class=java.awt.Image") but JavaFx seems to ignore the class parameter entirely and only map the mimetype to the content.